# HttpClient Download Image From URL Then Upload Image

Tags: c#, upload, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have an image that sits in a url.

https://somecdn/content/myimage.png

I want to pass this string to my API,Download the image into memory then upload to another API.

I'm using an api client that is generated from our swagger that takes a type of IO.stream.

Code is as follows:

```
    public async Task<int> UploadPicture(string fileUrl)
    {
        
        var otherApiClient = await _otherApiClient.Build();
        var fileRetrievalClient = new HttpClient();           

        var fileResponse = await fileRetrievalClient.GetAsync(fileUrl);
        

        var newId = await otherApiClient.UploadPictureAsync(file: await fileResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

        return newId;
    }
```

Normally when this is called via the front end the types are set correctly correctly:

*Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="yadayada.png"
Content-Type: image/png*

However in my code the Content-Type is wrong:

*Content-Type: **application/octet-stream**
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=**unknown***

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

**HttpClient** doesn't have a method called **UploadPictureAsync**. This indicates that the **Type** of variable **otherApiClient** is not **HttpClient**.

You need to check what other parameters you can pass to **UploadPictureAsync** and see how you can pass custom headers using the values from **fileResponse.Headers**

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
var fileResponse = await fileRetrievalClient.GetAsync(fileUrl);
byte[] bytes = await fileResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", "application/octet-stream name=test");
    var postResponse = await otherApiClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```